# HorizontalScrollView with very wide bitmaps

Tags: android

suppose that I have just one ImageView inside a HorizontalScrollView. The problem I'm facing is I have to create a very wide Bitmap to place it inside my ImageView and, obviously, use the scroll from HSV to see all my image there. I'm getting a lot of OutOfMemoryException so, is there any technique to get this task done without getting a ton of OutOfMemoryExceptions?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting OutOfMemoeryException because your bitmap is too large to load the entire bitmap into memory (a loading issue not a rendering issue).

Instead you need a custom image view that downsamples and/or only loads sections of the image at a time depending upon what part of the image should be currently visible.

[This](https://github.com/davemorrissey/subsampling-scale-image-view) may not fit your use case but it is an example of this problem being solved by downsampling